# Foreach displays from last to first

Tags: loop, php

I created the foreach loop to display post images, but It displays them from last to first, how can I make It to displays from first to last ;) ?

```
     <?php $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
      'post_status' => null,
       'post_parent' => $post->ID
     );

     $attachments = get_posts( $args );

 if ( $attachments ) {
   foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) : ?>
   <p>                    
      <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' ); ?>
      </p>

   <?php endforeach;    

 }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just pull them in the order you need instead of reversing the array?

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'attachment',
  'posts_per_page' => -1, // correct key is posts_per_page, not numberposts
  'orderby' => 'date'
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'post_parent' => $post->ID
);

$attachments = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: I don't think `post_date` is a possible order field, I think you meant `date`. I also wonder why you use `post_status` as `null` instead of `inherit`. But I agree with you on the method (+1) ;-)

Comment: Hm, but if I use post date, won't It show from the last one to the first ;) ?

Comment: @ birgirie. You're correct, `orderby` should be 'date'. Updated. Re `post_status`: I copy/pasted the query posted by the OP- figured the `null` value wasn't hurting anything so left it alone. It should probably just be removed since WordPress will select the appropriate status anyway: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/post.php#L1737

Answer (score 0):

Re-reverse the array!

```
     if ( $attachments ) {

$attachments = array_reverse( $attachments );

       foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) : ?>
       <p>                    
          <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' ); ?>
          </p>

       <?php endforeach;    

     }
```

Comment: So easy ;) Hm, but can you explain me, why It works this way ? I mean, why does It takes from last element instead of first ?

Comment: WP always returns posts (including attachments) with the most recent first, by default. You could also pass `order` and `orderby` arguments in your `get_posts` to change this if you wanted.